# Can't inject services into Angular entry components (Modal)

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx, web-component

I'm working on an Angular app where I have a material modal (entry component), I want to inject my AuthService and my ngrx store into that modal but whenever I open the modal I get those errors

```
core.js:4352 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[AuthService -> AuthService -> Store -> Store -> Store]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
```

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focusInitialElementWhenReady' of undefined
```

what should I do ?

Comment: I'd say you were way too superficial in your description. There's nothing special in injecting a service in a modal (you're probably missing some silly detail). But to help others with helping you, try to build a minimum reproduction in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ebeqpbdglov?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts). It's not uncommon to solve the problem trying to reproduce it. BTW, in the latest version of Angular, you don't need `entryComponents` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NullInjectorError` almost always mean, that you are missing some imports in your app or component module. In your case, the `Store` is missing. Best solution would be to provide the `StoreModule` in the `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // more imports
    StoreModule.forRoot() <--
  ],
  // more stuff
})
export class AppModule {}
```